# Data binding 15,000 items in a combobox is too slow

Tags: wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn

So as the title suggests, I have about 15,000 items and I'm trying to bind them to a ComboBox. well I have a data grid and I tried using a DataGridComboBoxColumn which was slow so I switched to a DataGridTemplateColumn using DataTemplates but it's not any faster. I've been searching online for a long time and I profiled my code and the majority of the time isn't being spent in my code. So my question is how would I speed that up? I'm pretty new to WPF and C#. My collection is a static ObservableCollection that I'm binding to the ItemsSource.

Comment: The answer is going to be "don't put 15,000 items in a combobox". Look for alternatives, like an auto-complete box or search box or something like that.

Comment: 15000 items in a combobox would require either a half hour of scrolling, or an incredibly granulated sliding bar, requiring pixel precision and then some more scrolling. Consider using an autocomplete.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. I shouldn't typically be displaying 15,000 items in a combo box, that's just the maximum. The average is around 6000 which is still a lot. I'll look at the autocomplete box thanks!

Comment: @user2013535: Regarding the above suggestions: Just set [`IsEditable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable.aspx) to `true`, you don't need a dedicated control in WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `ItemsPanel` of a `ComboBox` might be a `StackPanel`, which lacks virtualization, you could try to replace it with a `VirtualizingStackPanel` to see if that is the issue.

However this is still kind of a bad idea unless you use the `ComboBox`'s [keyboard input capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable.aspx).

Comment: Holy cow, I'm super surprised at how fast that loads now. there's no delay at all with 15,000 items. Thank you so much!

Comment: I should probably ask though, why isn't the default ItemsPanel a VirtualizingStackPanel? what's the downside?

Comment: @user2013535: You're welcome, glad that worked out. The scrolling is jumping from item to item in the `VirtualizingStackPanel` and thus not so smooth, however it could be implemented properly and retain that feature in theory.